# Rotate secondary group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a chart with multiple (2) groups on the X-Axis. The first group is Test Type and the second is Name and I want to Rotate the Outer Name from horizontal to -45 degrees. I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

Please let me know if it is possible to do so for the outer group.

Comment: Edit your question to include more details maybe a screenshot of what you are getting currently and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, either all the labels are rotated, or none.  Not the answer you were looking for, but I can't even think of a workaround for this question.